# Kubectl pod vs pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have noticed that when using kubectl you can pretty much use **pod** and **pods** interchangeably. Is there any instance when using one instead of the other could get you different results or can you just use either without worrying about it?

For example:

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get pod

kubectl describe pod/app
kubectl describe pods/app
```

and so on...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#syntax):

> Resource types are case-insensitive and you can specify the singular,
>   plural, or abbreviated forms. For example, the following commands
>   produce the same output:
>
> ```
> kubectl get pod pod1
> kubectl get pods pod1   
> kubectl get po pod1
> ```

It doesn't matter and both ways of writing will always result in the same result.

Comment: In addition, you can use the `kubectl api-resources` to see all the available shortnames (2nd column).